# JGSS GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE not working for kerberos service keytab

Tags: java, kerberos, jgss

I am testing the JGSS sample on my local domain but have a problem with hostbased service. Below is the setup:

1. obtain a keytab generated from command `ktpass -princ myservice/host.my.example.com@MY.EXAMPLE.COM -mapuser krbsrv@my.example.com -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCILAL -pass krbpass -out myservice-host.keytab`
2. system admin run `setspn -S myservice/host.my.example.com krbsrv` to set SPN for active directory.
3. from GssClient.java create the serverprincipal by:

   ```
   GSSName serverName = manager.createName(serverPrinc, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
   ```

   this will result in `java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))` exception.
4. but if I call `createName()` with `GSSName.NT_USER_NAME` there will be no error.
5. I have asked system admin and verified no duplicate for `setspn -L krbsrv` and `setspln-X myservice/host.my.example.com`.

So would there be anything I have messed up? The server is running on Solaris and client is running on Windows, both on Java 6u27.

Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your Java version is old, upgrade! Enable debug flags to see what actual GSS name is built for the hostbased service.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-O for the reply. I tested with Java 7u51 and debug enabled, it is reporting the same error. From GssServer side it's printing the principal as `myservice@host.my.example.com@MY.EXAMPLE.COM`.

Comment: How does your SPN look like? Maybe you are supplying the wrong format.

Comment: I am seeing the same SPN string from jaas.conf, GssServer printout, GssClient printout. The intriguing part is GssClient will succeed in `initSecContext` if I change code to `manager.createName(serverPrinc, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME)` but not for `GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE`.

Comment: how does `serverPrinc` look like?

Comment: for `serverPrinc` I have tried both `myservice@host.my.example.com@MY.EXAMPLE.COM` and `myservice@host.my.example.com`. I suppose it should have the realm info.

Comment: No, it is always service@FQDN.